# pascal to c++: trunc

Tags: c++, pascal

I have old pascal code

```
var i : longint;
    m : double;
begin
  .....
  i := trunc(m);
```

I have to convert it to C++ code.

An obvious thing here is to write

```
double m;
int i;
.....
i = static_cast<int>(std::trunc(m));
```

But the problem here is than pascal's trunc returns integer

```
function trunc(
  d: ValReal
):Int64;
```

while c++'s trunc returns double. 
Is it possible that for example trunc(2.3) will return 1.999999999999
and static_cast will make it 1 instead of 2? If yes is it correct to use static_cast without trunc to get same pascal's behavior?

```
i = static_cast<int>(m);
```

Comment: Sounds more like `round()`?

Comment: round returns nearest integer. in pascal I have trunc

Answer (score 2):

When you convert a floating-point value to an integer value in C++, the floating-point value is truncated automatically.

Take a look at the following simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double d = 12.98;
    int i = d;

    std::cout << "i = " << i << '\n';
}
```

The above program will print

```
i = 12
```

Conversions like these are done implicitly by the compiler. For more information please [read about implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) (specifically [read about floating-integral conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Floating.E2.80.93integral_conversions)).

However, it's important to note (from the linked reference):

> If the value cannot fit into the destination type, the behavior is undefined

So the floating point value, after truncation, must fit into the integer type on the left-hand side of the assignment.

Comment: OK so you suggesting static_cast<int>(m)?

Comment: @ArmanHunanyan No casting needed, the compiler will handle it anyway.

Comment: I know but I prefer explicit casting. The behaviours are same. Just coding style.

Comment: @ArmanHunanyan In that case it's okay, I like being explicit too, but not *that* much. :)

Answer (score 1):

All integers (and most longs?) are exactly representable in `double`. A function like `trunc` that's defined to return an integer in mathematical sense will never return something that's not an exact integer if its proper return value can be represented in `double`.